# Wordpress wp_set_auth_cookie() prevent duplicate users

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using the following code to log in users using the `wp_set_auth_cookie()` function in Wordpress:

```
    function auto_login() {
        $username = $_POST['user'];
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $user = get_userdatabylogin( $username );
            $user_id = $user->ID;
            wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
            do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );
        }     
        die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_auto_login', 'auto_login');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_auto_login', 'auto_login');
```

The problem I have is the same as this thread here:

[Authenticating users in WordPress using wp_set_auth_cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449596/authenticating-users-in-wordpress-using-wp-set-auth-cookie)

But since that question wasn't fully answered, here is my situation:

1. User 1 logs in to PC 1 with Username 1
2. User 2 logs in to PC 2 with Username 2
3. Username 1 is displayed as logged in instead

So my question is, how do I use the `wp_set_auth_cookie()` function to log in users whilst also preventing the same username to be displayed for ALL of my users?

**Update:** it appears that ALL of my users are now logged in automatically as User 1

Thanks

Comment: Try using using wp_signon() instead. This will authenticate the user. It actually calls wp_set_auth_cookie. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

Comment: The thing is, I'm using ajax to submit the login form after my page has finished loading, but it seems that wp_signon() needs to be run before any headers are sent? So before my page has loaded... So how do I modify my code to allow wp_signon() to be run via ajax?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a few deprecated functions and are not passing in the `username` properly - the variable `$user_login` is not set, you want to use `$user->user_login`. Also [`get_userdatabylogin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdatabylogin) has been deprecated in favor of [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by).

Try using the following, keep in mind that this does not validate the password. See the docs for [`wp_set_current_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user) for more info.

```
function auto_login() {
    // make sure user is not logged in and "user" was POST'd
    $username = isset( $_POST['user'] )? $_POST['user'] : false;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $username ){
        // load the user by username
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username ); 
        if ( $user ) {
            // log user in using the $user object properties
            wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
            do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so this manages to log me in, just like my function does, but it doesn't solve my issue of duplicate/conflicting logged in users... I'm still seeing the issue with wp_set_auth_cookie() causing ALL of my users to be logged in with the same user account

Comment: Are you user that 'user' is POST'ing with the correct username? Can you write it to the `error_log()` to check?